# django - when is .objects.get() evaluated?

Tags: python, django

Suppose i have :

```
class Library(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

class Books(models.Model):
    library = models.ForeignKey(Library)
    book = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

I want to create a new `Books`, we know we can fill the library on `Books` with just `Library`'s id, but we can also use instance of `Library`. My question is, is it better if we just provide the id? If i want to use the instance, then i have to evaluate using `.get()`, then does it hit the database?

Additional question : From the docs, queryset are lazy, it does not hit the database till evaluated, so when does queryset evaluated?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, `.get()` is immediately evaluated. Using IDs will avoid the database query, certainly.

`get` isn't lazy since it does not return a QuerySet - it returns a single instance of the model. QuerySets come from stuff like `.filter()`, so for example `Library.objects.filter(id=5)` is lazily evaluated while `Library.objects.get(id=5)` is immediately evaluated.

The actual evaluation of a QuerySet is covered in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) - basically, any time you actually pull out a value from the QuerySet, it will get evaluated. The complete list is this:

- Iteration
- Slicing
- Pickling
- `repr()`
- `len()`
- `list()`
- `bool()`

Comment: Note that slicing an unevaluated QuerySet usually returns another unevaluated QuerySet.

Comment: I believe get is lazy evaluated too. You do not hit the database until you access your variable https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/optimization/#understand-cached-attributes

Comment: @ppetrid That's talking about lookups of related variables. If you have django debug toolbar installed, it is pretty easy to verify that `get` is immediately evaluated by calling it inside a `debugsqlshell` - you'll see the query built and executed immediately.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this one, somehow I always thought it works like querysets do..

Comment: Would it be bad practice to use `.filter()` instead of `.get()` and then call `.first()` if/when you actually need the data just to force lazy evaluation?